# Centralizar input dentro de uma div utilizando materialize

Tags: css, materialize

Tenho um *form* com um *input* dentro, gostaria de deixar centralizado.
Eu consigo fazer isso no **custom.css** que eu tenho. Mas, como estou utilizando Materoalize, gostaria de saber se tem como fazer isso através dele.

```html
<form class="col s12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input placeholder="Digite seu nome" id="name" type="text">
      <label for="name" class="active">Nome</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input placeholder="Digite seu telefone" id="phone" type="tel">
      <label for="phone" class="active">Telefone</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input placeholder="Digite seu e-mail" id="email" type="email">
      <label for="email" class="active">E-mail</label>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Vc quer alinhar o forme como um todo ou os textos dentro do form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente colocar assim no seu html: form class="col s6 offset-s3"

Obs:Enviado por celular

Comment: Deu certo, só não entendi o cálculo das grids. No meu caso ficou input-field col s9 offset-s1

Answer (score 3):

Sim o Materialize tem uma classe especial para alinhar textos ao centro, a classe chama `center-align` aqui tem a documentação https://materializecss.com/helpers.html

Apesar disso só com ele vc não vai conseguir alinhar tudo. Nos `inputs` eu usei o `center-align` e funcionou direitinho, já para o label eu tive que customizar algumas classes.

Já para alinhar o form todo no meio da tela o grid tem que ser alinhado como o @Leandro falou. 3 - 6 - 3 ou 5 - 2 - 5 se quiser mais estreito, ou em e partes iguais como eu fiz `col s4 offset-s4`

Veja como ficou o resultado.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
    
.input-field label:not(.label-icon).active {
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    transform-origin: center;
}
.input-field.col label {
    left: 0;
}
.input-field label {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
 
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
<form class="col s12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s4 offset-s4">
        <input class="center-align" placeholder="Digite seu nome" id="name" type="text">
        <label for="name" class="active">Nome</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s4 offset-s4">
        <input class="center-align" placeholder="Digite seu telefone" id="phone" type="tel">
        <label for="phone" class="active">Telefone</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s4 offset-s4">
        <input class="center-align" placeholder="Digite seu e-mail" id="email" type="email">
        <label for="email" class="active">E-mail</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```